# A better expression for "sharing workshop in a company"

Tags: grammar, business-language

I am trying to find a better expression for this:

> I mean that the workshop is about the sharing of conversation with company people
>   so to improve company

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question, and perhaps try expressing the sentence in 2-3 more ways? That'll help us identify the clearest wording.

Comment: "The purpose of the workshop is to improve the company following discussion with the company's employees".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is probably better suited for the English Language Learners site.

Comment: You should at least start with something that makes sense, then we can try to suggest better ways to say it.

Comment: Actually, i want to ask to you of makes sense, but i am learner. so my english will be broken and not have makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is very difficult to understand. Users on EL&U are expected to be fluent in English. Please visit [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), a website especially created for learners of the English language. Good luck!

Comment: I have "translated" your question for the ELL site, so that it stands a better chance of being accepted there. Users in ELL have to know *some* English too! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume future tense.

*We are going to have a workshop.  The workshop will enable company people to collaborate and create improvements for the company.*